# Gmail—add star to all emails received

Tags: gmail

I'd like all emails received to my Gmail account to be starred. I've set up a filter for `*`, but this also stars messages in my Sent Mail. I can't use `to:myaddress@gmail.com` because I have a catch-all (Google Apps). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If a filter with criteria `*` is working for you with the exception of the sent messages, you might try

```
* AND !is:sent
```

Alternately, see if your wildcard will cause received mail to fall within scope of the following

```
to:me
```

I don't know offhand if `to:me` triggers on your primary address, or uses a more comprehensive method of matching.

Incidentally, what are you trying to accomplish by starring all incoming messages? Some kind of "sticky" indicator of read/unread (or "handled") status?

Comment: to:me doesn't include the catch-all. Unfortunately "* AND !is:sent" doesn't work either! I'd like to be able to read messages, but only 'forget' about them when I've really read them. Don't want to use archiving.

Comment: @Chris: Archiving does **exactly** what you describe. Why not use it?

Comment: It changes what I'm used to, but that's what I've set up now! 17000 conversations have been archived... thanks.

Comment: Actually... on my Android phone, I can't sync "All Mail". Reverting back...